# How to automate creating or uploading intents in Dialogflow/api.ai using java?

Tags: java, rest, api, dialogflow-es

I want to create intents in dialog flow through java programming not want to crate or upload it manually,so Is there any API in java or process to create intent through programs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `/intents` API from dialogflow to do this

https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents